# How can share state variable between components in REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native

I have 2 components A and B.
How can pass a variable from component A to component B ?

**ComponentA.js**

```
const ComponentA = () => {

    //INSET
    const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
    //GET HEADER HEIGHT
    const [heightHeader, setHeightHeader] = useState(false)


    return (
    <View 
    onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    const { height } = nativeEvent.layout
    setHeightHeader(height)
    }}>
    </View>
      )
    }
    
export default ComponentA
```

> I want to get from `const [heightHeader, setHeightHeader] = useState(false)`
> the **heightHeader** variable

**ComponentB.js**

```
import ComponentA from './ComponentA';

const ComponentB = () => {


return (
<View style={{
      flex:1
      }}>


<View style={{
flex:1,
paddingTop: heightHeader,
}}>
</View>
</View>
  )
}

export default ComponentB
```

> I want to get **heightHeader** variable from ComponentA to ComponentB.

*The 2 Components isn't in the same file

Comment: You can use Context API or Redux Toolkit if component B is not called in component A. If Component B is called in A then let me know I will provide you a solution for the same !!

Answer (score 1):

You need a Parent Component.

For Example in your app.js File you set the State heigthHeader. And in the return you pass the state as a Prop to your Components like this:

ComponentA:

```
const ComponentA = (props) => {

//INSET
const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
//GET HEADER HEIGHT



return (
<View 
onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
const { height } = nativeEvent.layout
props.setHeightHeader(height)
}}>
</View>
  )
export default ComponentA
}
```

ComponentB:

```
const ComponentB = (props) => {


return (
<View style={{
      flex:1
      }}>


<View style={{
flex:1,
paddingTop: props.heightHeader,
}}>
</View>
</View>
  )
}

export default ComponentB
```

App.js:

```
const [heightHeader, setHeightHeader] = useState(props.heigthHeader)
...
return(<>
<ComponentA setHeightHeader=setHeightHeader/> 
<ComponentB heightHeader=heightHeader/>
</>
...
```

Comment: No isn't the only way.

Comment: You could also use a Database, AsyncStorage if you want to transfer Data. But for States you have to do it in that way